# How to shear rectangle without moving it?

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles

I'd like to ask whether it is possible to shear object without actually moving it. Here's the code I'm doing it right now

```
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.Shear(2, 0);            

        g.Transform = matrix ;
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100));
        g.ResetTransform();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shear factors are relative to the origin of the coordinate system.

So to keep the shear result at the 'same' location you need to add a translation matrix.

1. Create a translation that moves the point that should be static to the origin of the coordinate system. In the example the static point is (200,300) so the translation is (-200, -300)
2. apply the translation
3. Shear
4. create the inverse of the translation. In the example: (200, 300)
5. apply the inverse translation

**BTW: Make sure you `Dispose` the matrices and other GDI+ objects!!**

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Translate(200, 300);
matrix.Shear(2, 0);            
matrix.Translate(-200, -300);
g.Transform = matrix ;
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100));
g.ResetTransform();
```

Or

```
using (var g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    using(Matrix translation = new Matrix(),
                 reverseTranslation = translation.Clone(),
                 sheer = new Matrix()
                 combination = new Matrix())
    {
        translation.Translate(200, 300);
        reverseTranslation.Invert();
        sheer.Shear(2, 0);
        combination.Multiply(translation);
        combination.Multiply(sheer);
        combination.Multiply(reverseTranslation);

        g.Transform = combination;
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100));
        g.ResetTransform();
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: and how could I count values to translate it? I can't get it working

Comment: I added the steps to my answer

Comment: and how to 'create the inverse of translation'? shall I use function invert? it doesn't take any arguments

Comment: You can create a translation matrix with the translation so when you call Invert it will be changed into the inverse translation. You can also do it by hand as I added in my example.

Comment: Your code draws just a 1 rectangle (not sheared). I guess matrix.translate(2,0) moves it far away but still, It's not working.

Comment: I editted my answer. Matrices need to be order in reverse... beginners mistake :) Sorry

Comment: I added a slightly different implementation that uses the Invert method

Comment: Added a warning about Disposing GDI+ objects. Matrices and other graphic objects need to be disposed!

Comment: What happens if I don't dispose them?

Comment: The application will leak memory and that will hurt if you are drawing many objects over time. Rule of thumb: if an object implements IDisposable, use `using` to make sure it releases its umanaged memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do:

1. Translate the lower-left corner of your rectangle to the origin.
   Let the offset be `(-dX, -dY)`.
2. Apply your shear transform.
3. Apply the inverse translation to your rectangle, i.e., `(dX, dY)`.